# Putting ISP public IPs on two different firewalls

Tags: routing, ip, router, isp, ip-routing

Trying to figure out if I need a router or switch for this.

Nothing is yet configured, and I can still order equipment.

I have incoming: Two internet connections. One (ISP-1) of which has given us a /29 with 5 usable IPs.

I have a Juniper firewall that I want to put between my network and the internet.

I also have another firewall or router (I think an edgewater) being connected to ISP-2 for voip, and behind that will be a their own switch for phones and stuff, not part of my data network.

voip provider would like to use one of the IPs from ISP-1 as a failover if ISP-2 goes down to keep phones working. I would like to let them put the public IP into the 2nd wan on their router.
I would prefer not to plug voip provider's wan-2 into the Juniper.

ISP-1 is installing a router somewhere in the building which I have an ethernet cable coming from to the network rack.

Here's what ISP-1 has given me in an email, trying to get one of their tech's on the phone this week has been difficult at best:

```
a.b.c.56/29 (255.255.255.248)
a.b.c.56 - network
a.b.c.57 - gateway
a.b.c.58 - .62 - usable IPs
a.b.c.63 - broadcast
```

Do I

1. plug ethernet from the ISP's router into a switch, plug the Juniper
   WAN and Edgewater WAN into the switch, and give them each ip .58 and
   .59 with gateway .57 respectively?
2. plug ethernet from the ISP's router into the WAN of an as yet un-purchased router, set its WAN address to .56, and use extra IPs on the lan side, still plugging .58 and .59 into the WAN on the juniper and edgewater?

Other stuff: If I whois any of the IPs given, they show up as one registered block. Where the hell does a.b.c.56 come in when configuring stuff, possibly for ISP-1's router?

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, ISP1 was providing routing for their IPs. So I did the following:
ISP1 -> Gigabit Switch
- Gigabit Switch -> Juniper Router -> LAN
- Gigabit Switch -> Edgewater (voip) -> phone LAN